# Preference Fragment not showing preferences

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get a preference screen to load, but it does not seem to be showing. I am able to load the Activity, but I can see no actual preferences. I have tried other solution on StackOverflow like adding    `setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);` to the SettingsActivity, but had no success.

SettingsActivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SettingsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Display the fragment as the main content.
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
    }

}
```

preferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/pref_start"
        android:key="pref_key_storage_settings">
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="pref_key_auto_exit"
            android:summary="@string/pref_summary_exit"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_exit"
            android:defaultValue="false"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

SettingsFragment.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    public SettingsFragment() {
    }

    public void onCreate(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does `android.R.id.content` not exist kn my current activity? I thought `android.R.id.content` was the root element of the activity?

Comment: Off topic: You want to do the fragment transaction only when `savedInstanceState == null`. You only need to do it once when the user opens the activity. After the user rotates the screen it will remain loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Since your activity extends `ActionBarActivity` which in turn extends `FragmentActivity` it can only use support `Fragment`s and their descendants. However the `PreferenceFragment` descends from native `Fragment`. Even if your minimum SDK is higher than 11 these two are not able to interoperate.

You have two options:

**1) Go native preferences**

Your activity would best extend `PreferenceActivity`. You can then continue using your current `PreferenceFragment`. The downside is you'll have to handle styling on API 11+ (or 14+) and API 21+ separately (but it can be done). [Full documentation on native preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html)

**2) EASY: Go full support**

There is a community made backport of `PreferenceFragment` (actually there are multiple, but I used this one) which can be found here: https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment

You should be able to compile just after importing the library to your project and changing the import statement so instead of `import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;` you'd have `import android.support.v4.preference.PreferenceFragment;`.

**How to decide**

If you target API below 11 and you need the action bar you have no choice but option 2. This option is also best if you don't need the `PreferenceActivity` sugar like headers, master-detail view on large screens etc. (again see the docs)